# SwiftUI ScrollView gesture recogniser

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture-recognition, swiftui-scrollview

How can I detect when a ScrollView is being dragged?

Within my ScrollView I have an `@Binding scrollPositionOffset` variable that I watch with `.onChange(of:)` and then programmatically scroll to that position using `ScrollViewReader.scrollTo()`. This works great, but I need to also update `scrollPositionOffset` when I scroll the ScrollView directly. I'm struggling to do that as this would trigger the `.onChange(of:)` closure and get into a loop.

My solution is to conditionally call `ScrollViewReader.scrollTo()` only when I have a `localScrolling` variable set to false. I've tried to set this using `DragGesture.onChanged` and `.onEnded`, but this isn't the same as the drag gesture that causes the scroll, so `.onEnded` never fires.

What I think I need is a @GestureRecognizer for ScrollView similar to UIScrollView's `isDragging` or `isTracking` (I'm aware I could use UIScrollView, but I don't know how, and that seems like it might be more work!! I'd accept an answer that shows me how to drop that into a SwiftUIView too)

**Context** (in case anyone has a cleaner solution to my actual scenario):

I have a ScrollView that I'm programmatically scrolling to create an effect like the Minimap view within Xcode (i.e. I have a zoomed-out view adjacent to the ScrollView, and dragging the minimap causes the ScrollView to scroll).

This works great when I use the minimap, but I'm struggling to get the reverse to happen: moving the position of the ScrollView to update the minimap view.

**Code**

```
@Binding var scrollPositionOffset: CGFloat
let zoomMultiplier:CGFloat = 1.5

 var body: some View{
        
        ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                ScrollView {
                    ZStack(alignment:.top){

         //The content of my ScrollView

                    MagnifierView()
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * zoomMultiplier)
                    
         //I'm using this as my offset reference

                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height:10)
                            .alignmentGuide(.top) { _ in
                                geometry.size.height * zoomMultiplier * -scrollPositionOffset
                            }
                            .id("scrollOffset")    
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(){
                    scrollViewProxy.scrollTo("scrollOffset", anchor: .top)
                }
                
                .onChange(of: scrollPositionOffset, perform: { _ in
            
        //Only call .scrollTo() if the view isn't already being scrolled by the user

                    if !localScrolling {
                    scrollViewProxy.scrollTo("scrollOffset", anchor: .top)
                    }
                    
                })
                
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged{gesture in
                            localScrolling = true
                            
                            let offset = gesture.location.y/(zoomMultiplier * geometry.size.height)

                            scrollPositionOffset = offset
                        }
        
                        .onEnded({gesture in

     //Doesn't ever fire when scrolling

                            localScrolling = false
                        })
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`ScrollViewStyle`](https://github.com/TimmysApp/ScrollViewStyle):

```
struct CustomScrollView: ScrollViewStyle {
    @Binding var isDragging: Bool
    func make(body: AnyView, context: Context) -> some View {
        body
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    class Coordinator: ScrollViewCoordinator {
        var parent: CustomScrollView
        init(parent: CustomScrollView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
            parent.isDragging = false
        }
        func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            parent.isDragging = true
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var isDragging = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
        }.scrollViewStyle(CustomScrollView(isDragging: $isDragging))
    }
}
```

**Version 2.0.0 Update:**

All you have to do now is:

1. Add a property to track the state of the `ScrollView`

   ```
   @ScrollState var state
   ```
2. Use the `scrollViewStyle` modifier

   ```
   .scrollViewStyle(.defaultStyle($state))
   ```

TestView:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ScrollState var state
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ...
        }.scrollViewStyle(.defaultStyle($state))
        .onChange(of: state.isDragging) { newValue in
            print(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```